# C Programming convert String representation of Hex to Hex

Tags: c, string, hex

I am fairly new to C.
I would like to convert a String representation of a HEX number to a actual Hex number ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
    {
        char buf[8] = "410C0000";
        printf("%s\n",buf);
        return 0;
    }
```

I would like to break up the string and convert it into 4 inividual Hex numbers. 
Which i can process further for calculations                              :

```
0x41 0x0C 0x00 0x00
```

Comment: `buf` - as being of size 8 - will not contain a string terminating `'\0'`. Write `char buf[9]` if you want to use `buf` as a string as well, e.g. when writing `printf("%s\n",buf)`

Comment: What is actual **HEX** number. If I have a int variable how can I know if it is hex, octal, binary or decimal. Or maybe it is just the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sscanf`, which is a variant of `scanf` that reads from a string rather than from a stdin or a file. Format specifier `%X` specifies to treat the input as a hexadecimal number, `%02X` additionally says to read exactly two digits, and `%02hhX` additionally defines to store the result into a single byte (i.e. an `unsigned char`, instead of a probably 64 bit integral value).

The code could look as follows:

```
int main()
{
    char buf[8] = "410C0000";

    unsigned char h0=0, h1=0, h2=0, h3=0;
    sscanf(buf+6, "%02hhX", &h0);
    sscanf(buf+4, "%02hhX", &h1);
    sscanf(buf+2, "%02hhX", &h2);
    sscanf(buf+0, "%02hhX", &h3);
    printf("0x%02X 0x%02X 0x%02X 0x%02X\n",h3, h2, h1, h0);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x41 0x0C 0x00 0x00
```

BTW: `buf` - as being of size 8 - will not contain a string terminating `'\0'`, so you will not be able to use it in `printf`. Write `char buf[9]` if you want to use `buf` as a string as well, e.g. when writing `printf("%s\n",buf)`.